# Como verificar se a expressão LINQ não vem null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Eu tenho esta expressão LINQ:

```
MaterialImage mainImage = images.First(i => i.IsMainImage == true);
```

O meu problema é que **images.First(i => i.IsMainImage == true)** pode devolver null se não tiver nenhuma imagem com a propriedade **IsMainImage** marcada como true. Qual é a melhor maneira de verificar se deu null e usar outra igualdade para colocar um valor no **mainImage**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx), se não tiver retorno ele retorna o valor padrão da classe que é `null` (*isso varia de acordo com o tipo, se for um `int` por exemplo o retorno é 0 como valor padrão*).

```
MaterialImage mainImage = images.FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsMainImage == true);
if (mainImage != null)
{ 
     // teve retorno;
}
```

Esse `Default` do método do [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) é a mesma coisa que [default(T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25tdedf5.aspx) e como já foi relatado dependendo do tipo ele coloca o seu valor padrão.

***Por exemplo:***

```
using System;

public class Carros
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(default(int));
        System.Console.WriteLine(default(long));
        System.Console.WriteLine(default(DateTime));
        System.Console.WriteLine(default(Carros) == null);
    }
}
```

***Saída:***

```
0
0
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
True
```

[***Exemplo OnLine***](http://ideone.com/m9ixgC)

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [FirstOrDefault - Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [default Keyword in Generic Code (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [default](https://www.dotnetperls.com/default)
- [What is the use of `default` keyword in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727346/what-is-the-use-of-default-keyword-in-c)

Comment: O que ele vai buscar se for **Default**?

Comment: @ihavenokia fiz a edição, se ele não encontrar retorna `null`!

Comment: ok, então a diferença é que com o **Default** ele guarda null em vez de dar exception?

Comment: O `OrDefault` verifica se houve retorno se não ele dá um default(T) onde T é o tipo do retorno, que no seu caso é uma classe e toda classe o valor padrão é `null` vou melhorar a resposta.

Comment: ja vi as alterações, ficou 5* :)

Comment: @ihavenokia vlw